# is it possible to change ms access table name with python

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

I have several ms access databases that each have a table named `PlotStatus-name-3/13/12`.

I need to import each of these tables into a `.csv` table. If I manually change the name of the tables to `PlotStatus_name_3_13_12`, this code works. **Does anyone know how to change the table namees using python?**

```python
#connect to access database
for filename in os.listdir(prog_rep_local):
if filename[-6:] == ".accdb":
    DBtable = os.path.join(prog_rep_local, filename)
    conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=' + DBtable)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    ct = cursor.tables
    for row in ct():
        rtn = row.table_name
        if rtn[:10] == "PlotStatus":

            #this does not work:
            #Oldpath = os.path.join(prog_rep_local, filename, rtn)
            #print Oldpath
            #fpr = Oldpath.replace('-', '_')#.replace("/","_")
            #print fpr
            #newname = os.rename(Oldpath, fpr)  this does not work
            #print newname
            #spqaccdb = "SELECT * FROM " + newname


            #this workds if I manually change the table names in advance
            sqlaccdb = "SELECT * FROM " + rtn
            print sqlaccdb

            cursor.execute(sqlaccdb)
            rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easier solution would be to just add brackets around the table name so that the /s don't throw off the SQL command interpreter.

```
sqlaccdb = "SELECT * FROM [" + rtn + "]"
```

Comment: Thanks!  I can't upvote you because I have no reputation points.

Comment: @user15042 did it for you! Good luck!