# Reorganize MS Access DB via Python Script

Tags: python, vba, ms-access

I need to reorganize an access db and would like to do this via python.

[Access GUI of the ReOrg Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zY04.png)

So I wrote the following:

```
import win32com.client

# path to Access-DB
db_path = 'C:/Access-DB.accdb'

access_app = win32com.client.Dispatch('Access.Application')
access_app.Visible = False
access_app.OpenCurrentDatabase(db_path)

# ReOrg Access DB
access_app.DoCmd.RunCommand(4)

access_app.Quit()
```

It runs through without an error, but the size of the db file is the same afterwards. If I do it manually it will reduze the size.

I should mention that I'm able to open the files from the machine on which I run the scripts, but I don't have a valid office license on that machine. But the reorganize feature is still available for manual use.

Since I can't find documentation about access_app.DoCmd.RunCommand(4) I'm not sure if this is even the correct command.

I thought about putting the reorg in an VBA macro and run

> access_app.DoCmd.RunMacro('MacroName')

instead, but I don't know how to call the reorg feature in a macro aswell.

Comment: Hello welcome to Stackoverflow. Have you searched the site for similar questions? Let me ask you a different question. 1) If you are doing manually, what are your planned steps for *reorganizing* the Acc db (do you want to split, rearrange columns, tables?)? 2) Is there any reasons you didn't use `pyodbc`? Would these questions be of some assistance to you? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64203246/1389394) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15304779/1389394)

Comment: @bonCodigo the reorganzise feature is a button in access. I'm not aware of the sql commands behind. I use pyodbc in other scripts, but since I do not know what access is doing here (other than fixing corrupt db files) I was not able to use pyodbc. But if there is a way to use it, I would prefer pyodbc over any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

The command is correct:

```
DoCmd.RunCommand(acCmdCompactDatabase)
```

However, you can't do this, neither by calling a macro.

And, obviously not, as what's happening when compacting an Access database is, that the file is written to a temp file, this is validated, then the original file is deleted, and the temp file is renamed to the original name.

To me, this command seems useless.